# IoC Instantiate latest time possible

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

In  my application I have many services with I use the following pattern:
In the same file as the interface I define a static factory method which is controlled by the IoC container as follows:

```
public interface ISomethingService {
    Task DoSomethingAsync(int id);
}

public class SomethingServicFactory : ServiceFactory<ISomethingService > { }

public class ServiceFactory<T>
{
    public static Func<T> CreateClosure;
    public T GetDefault() => CreateClosure();
}
```

After creating and configuring the IoC container:

```
SomethingServicFactory .CreateClosure = () => 
    Container.GetInstance<ISomethingService >();
```

Later in my application when I need a SomethingService:

```
var somethingService= new SomethingService().GetDefault();
```

This allows me to defer creation until the last moment yet still control the service creation using the container. I just started using SimpleInjector.
More importantly it allows me to create an instance of the service and easily pass it parameters while giving control to the IoC.

A great example where this pattern helps me is in a WPF XAML instantiated user control that needs to populate data (i.e. lookup values from a database).  In the code behind I am able to easily create a DbContext and get data from the database. However, I have come to use it throughout the application as well.

I am concerned that I am missing a significant design/architecture problem by using this pattern and I am looking for comments on this pattern by IoC experts.

Comment: This sounds a lot like `Lazy<T>`

Answer (score 7):

Your design exposes the following code smells and anti-patterns:

- [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/): Your `CreateClosure` property forces you to initialize your service factory after its creation. When you forget this, the application will fail at runtime. Temporal Coupling is a code smell.
- [Ambient Context](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition/chapter-5/section-5-3): The `CreateClosure` acts as an Ambient Context (which is much like the Singleton design pattern, but with the ability to change the value using a static method or property). This causes a class's dependencies to be hidden, instead of 'statically declared' using the class's constructor. In [Dependency Injection in .NET 2nd edition](https://www.manning.com/seemann2/), we consider Ambient Context an anti-pattern (see chapter 5).
- [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) violation: Your factories are concrete classes, while the DIP promotes talking to interfaces. As a result, your code becomes strongly coupled and hard to test.
- [Abstract Factories are a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100): When applying Dependency Injection, the usefulness of factories evaporates. Especially the idea of having a factory for every abstraction in your application is an absolute no-no.

Instead, with Dependency Injection, everything becomes much easier: When we apply **Constructor Injection**, we can simply inject `ISomethingService` into its consumers. This:

- Makes it clear what dependencies a class has, by looking at the constructor
- Allows the DI container to compose the object graph for you and do analysis and diagnostics on the graph
- Allows the container to manage lifetime of objects
- Removes the need for having factories (since the container will take that role)
- Reduces the number of dependencies a class has. Instead of needing 2 (one for the factory and one for the service), you only need one (for the service).